# Curator Background operation retry gave up

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

My code is like this:

```
String zkAddress = "...";  // example
ExponentialBackoffRetry retryPolicy = new ExponentialBackoffRetry(1000, 3);
CuratorFramework client = CuratorFrameworkFactory.builder()
                    .connectString(zkAddress)
                    .retryPolicy(retryPolicy)
                    .build();
client.start();
```

The curator-framework version is 3.1.0. I got an error listed below.

```
18:31:20.839 [Curator-Framework-0] ERROR org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl - Background operation retry gave up
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99) ~[zookeeper-3.5.1-alpha.jar:3.5.1-alpha-1693007]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.checkBackgroundRetry(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:802) [curator-framework-3.1.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.performBackgroundOperation(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:931) [curator-framework-3.1.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.backgroundOperationsLoop(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:883) [curator-framework-3.1.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.access$300(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:69) [curator-framework-3.1.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$4.call(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:310) [curator-framework-3.1.0.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_77]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_77]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.8.0_77]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_77]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_77]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_77]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is resulted from that machine has no authority to access the zookeeper server. I have change to another machine and it works right.

Comment: what do you mean "no authority"?